# Behavior (wave or particle) of the photon absorbed by an electron

Tags: waves, photons, electrons, elementary-particles, absorption

After being absorbed by an electron, does a photon continue to behave like a particle, or like a wave, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"After being absorbed by an electron" this means that photon does not exist anymore.